# What were the main discoveries in Biology?

Tags: human-biology, zoology, brain

What were the greatest achievements in Biology? Can you please provide a short list of discoveries that you would consider as being the most important discoveries of the history of Biology.

Comment: I edited the post to match my answer (as I misread the question to start with). The post is now on-topic I think and I am voting to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few things coming to my mind

- [Discovery of cells by Robert Hook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_theory#Discovery_of_cells)
- [Discovery of bacteria by Antonie Philips van Leeuwenhoek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonie_van_Leeuwenhoek)
- [Discovery of antibiotics by Alexander Flemming](https://explorable.com/history-of-antibiotics)
- [The basis of heredity by Gregor Mendel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregor_Mendel)
- [Evolution (On the origin of species by C. Darwin)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Origin_of_Species)
- [Watson and Crick discovery of DNA structure](http://www.nature.com/physics/looking-back/crick/index.html)
- [Vaccination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaccination)
- [The concept of ecosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecosystem#History_and_development)

Comment: yes they were incredible :D but i meant UN discovered things in biology which would be awesome :)

Comment: OP says *would be*, not *what were*

Comment: It always amazes me that a Canadian like you has trouble with these things, being so 'close' to the US. I have to visit Canada some day to pick up the flavor of it. Nonetheless, nice list +1 I would even recommend editing the question in line with your interpretation, because your interpretation is less pob (but still is), while the original question is definitely going to be closed.

Comment: @Christiaan I definitely misread the post indeed. I edited the post as you invited me to do. I feel quite proud when you call me "Canadian". In reality I have lived in Canada (Vancouver, BC) for the past 1.5 years but grew up in Switzerland.

Comment: That explains everything haha. Both very nice and interesting countries.  I'll vote to reopen. But it may still be pob...

Comment: @Christiaan Actually, in this context, the OP's *would be* is equivalent to *what were*. If you were to rephrase the "would be" expression, it could be something like "what would you consider to be some of the greatest achievements". People commonly use the two interchangeably in colloquial speech here in the US. Although if you want to to be technical about it, the OP 'should' have said "were", but this is SE Bio, anyway, not ELU :)

Comment: @AleksandrH - touche :)

Comment: Oh indeed! I like to think that this is why I understood the post the way I did. Thanks @AleksandrH

Comment: I don't understand the 2 down votes I received. Comments are welcome.